# "You Typed an Invalid name for a sheet or chart", Need to update the code

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

When my "copy pivot table" code creates pivot tables I have a brand that has a "/".  Tabs in excel can't be created/named with "/", once it sees that it debugs and stops creating pivot tables.  Is there a code i can include to tell it when it sees "RE/DONE" to change the name to "RE DONE" so it can create the pivot table without debugging.  My code is below.

```
On Error GoTo errHandler
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim strPF As String
Dim strPI As String

Set ws = Sheets("Invoice PVTTBL Template")
Set pt = ws.PivotTables(1)
Set pf = pt.PageFields(1)
strPF = pf.Name

For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
  strPI = Left(pi.Name, 31)
  On Error Resume Next
    Sheets(strPI).Delete
  On Error GoTo 0
  ws.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
  With ActiveSheet
    .Name = strPI
    With .PivotTables(1).PivotFields(strPF)
      .PivotItems(pi.Name).Visible = True
      .CurrentPage = pi.Name
    End With
  End With

Next pi

ws.Activate

MsgBox "Invoices Created"

exitHandler:
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  Exit Sub
errHandler:
  MsgBox "Could not create sheets"
  Resume exitHandler

End Sub
```

Comment: `strPI = Replace(Left(pi.Name, 31), "/", " ")`

Comment: thank you!!!! do i replace strPI = left(pi.name, 31) , with the new coding you sent? I just want to confirm that i have other names in the file that do not have "/" just want to make sure if i change that code it will still be able to create other pivot tables even if the name does not have "/".

Comment: Yes - replace `strPI = left(pi.name, 31)` with what I posted.  It will not have any effect on names which do not contain `/`

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!